# Acer Laptop, using Windows 8 & the newest version of explorer

Tags: windows-8

I bought an Acer laptop the other day & for what-ever reason Acer has permanently set Bing as my homepage.  I keep re- setting MSN as my homepage, but then the next day Bing is back.  I have tried Tool, Internet Options, General Tab, keying in the MSN site, Apply & finally OKAY.  This is starting to drive me nuts that I can't change my homepage on Explorer.  Does anyone have a solution?????

Answer (score 0):

try setting it with local policy and see what happens.

launch gpedit.msc and browse to User Configuration / Admin Templates / Windows Components / Internet Explorer and open up "Disable changing home page settings".

Enable the policy and specify the homepage to be used. Good luck